# Qt cross compilation *QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program* error

Tags: cross-compilation, qt

I am using the QT Creator for my laptop (Linux LMDE 3 Cindy OS) And for Raspberry Zero Cross-compiling.

I have installed the QT based of [this instruction](https://mechatronicsblog.com/cross-compile-and-deploy-qt-5-12-for-raspberry-pi/) and by this setting:

```
    mkdir ~/raspi
    cd ~/raspi
    git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools
    mkdir sysroot sysroot/usr sysroot/opt

    rsync -avz pi@raspberrypi_ip:/lib sysroot
    rsync -avz pi@raspberrypi_ip:/usr/include sysroot/usr
    rsync -avz pi@raspberrypi_ip:/usr/lib sysroot/usr
    rsync -avz pi@raspberrypi_ip:/opt/vc sysroot/opt
wget http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.12/5.12.3/single/ qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3.tar.xz
tar xvf  qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3.tar.xz
cd  qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3
```

> ./configure -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi-g++
>   -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
>   -sysroot ~/raspi/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -skip qtwayland -skip qtlocation -skip qtscript -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix ~/raspi/qt5pi -hostprefix ~/raspi/qt5 -no-use-gold-linker -v -no-gbm

```
    make
    make install
```

but when i go to my **QT Creator** and i have built a sample **Qt Widget Application**.
My  `new_sd.pro` file is this kind:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2019-06-09T18:56:52
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = new_sd
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.https://forum.qt.io/topic/103716/qt-cross-compilation-qopenglshaderprogram-could-not-create-shader-program-error
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /home/pi/Desktop/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

My raspy kit setting is shown here:
[image]

AND My **qt Raspberry Compiler** setting is shown Below:
[image]

,SO when i get this error:

```
11:57:14: Checking available ports...
11:57:15: Found 101 free ports.
11:57:15: Starting gdbserver --multi :10000...
11:57:15: Debugging starts
Listening on port 10000
Remote debugging from host 192.168.7.1
Process /home/pi/Desktop/new_sd/bin/new_sd created; pid = 3503
Could not load shared library symbols for 3 libraries, e.g. /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?Could not load shared library symbols for 3 libraries, e.g. /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so.Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-brcm-integration.so.Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so.Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.so.Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so.Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so.Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqmng.so.Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?Could not load shared library symbols for 2 libraries, e.g. /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so.Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.so.Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.so.Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.so.Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.so.Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?




 QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program
        QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
        Could not link shader program:
         ""
```

**Update:**
I get debugger log and could be seen here:

```
>
 Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsystemd.so.0 loaded.
>=library-loaded,id="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0",target-name="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0",host-name="/home/so/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0 loaded.
>=library-loaded,id="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libffi.so.6",target-name="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libffi.so.6",host-name="/home/so/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libffi.so.6",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libffi.so.6 loaded.
>=library-loaded,id="/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libselinux.so.1",target-name="/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libselinux.so.1",host-name="/home/so/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libselinux.so.1",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libselinux.so.1 loaded.
>=library-loaded,id="/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblzma.so.5",target-name="/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblzma.so.5",host-name="/home/so/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblzma.so.5",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblzma.so.5 loaded.
>=library-loaded,id="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblz4.so.1",target-name="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblz4.so.1",host-name="/home/so/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblz4.so.1",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblz4.so.1 loaded.
>=library-loaded,id="/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcrypt.so.20",target-name="/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcrypt.so.20",host-name="/home/so/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcrypt.so.20",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcrypt.so.20 loaded.
>=library-loaded,id="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgmodule-2.0.so.0",target-name="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgmodule-2.0.so.0",host-name="/home/so/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgmodule-2.0.so.0",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 loaded.
>=library-loaded,id="/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libresolv.so.2",target-name="/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libresolv.so.2",host-name="/home/so/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libresolv.so.2",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libresolv.so.2 loaded.
>=library-loaded,id="/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmount.so.1",target-name="/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmount.so.1",host-name="/home/so/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmount.so.1",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmount.so.1 loaded.
>=library-loaded,id="/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgpg-error.so.0",target-name="/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgpg-error.so.0",host-name="/home/so/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgpg-error.so.0",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgpg-error.so.0 loaded.
>=library-loaded,id="/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libblkid.so.1",target-name="/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libblkid.so.1",host-name="/home/so/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libblkid.so.1",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libblkid.so.1 loaded.
>=library-loaded,id="/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libuuid.so.1",target-name="/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libuuid.so.1",host-name="/home/so/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libuuid.so.1",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libuuid.so.1 loaded.
>&"warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 3 libraries, e.g. /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so.\nUse the \"info sharedlibrary\" command to see the complete listing.\nDo you need \"set solib-search-path\" or \"set sysroot\"?"
 Could not load shared library symbols for 3 libraries, e.g. /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so.
 Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
 Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
>&"\n"

>=library-loaded,id="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-brcm-integration.so",target-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-brcm-integration.so",host-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-brcm-integration.so",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-brcm-integration.so loaded.
>&"warning: Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-brcm-integration.so.\nDo you need \"set solib-search-path\" or \"set sysroot\"?"
 Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-brcm-integration.so.
 Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
>&"\n"

>=library-loaded,id="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so",target-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so",host-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so loaded.
>&"warning: Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so.\nDo you need \"set solib-search-path\" or \"set sysroot\"?"
 Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so.
 Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
>&"\n"

>=library-loaded,id="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.so",target-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.so",host-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.so",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.so loaded.
>&"warning: Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.so.\nDo you need \"set solib-search-path\" or \"set sysroot\"?"
 Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.so.
 Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
>&"\n"

>=library-loaded,id="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so",target-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so",host-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so loaded.
>&"warning: Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so.\nDo you need \"set solib-search-path\" or \"set sysroot\"?"
 Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so.
 Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
>&"\n"

>=library-loaded,id="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so",target-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so",host-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so loaded.
>=library-loaded,id="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so.62",target-name="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so.62",host-name="/home/so/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so.62",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so.62 loaded.
>&"warning: Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so.\nDo you need \"set solib-search-path\" or \"set sysroot\"?"
 Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so.
 Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
>&"\n"

>=library-loaded,id="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqmng.so",target-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqmng.so",host-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqmng.so",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqmng.so loaded.
>=library-loaded,id="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmng.so.1",target-name="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmng.so.1",host-name="/home/so/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmng.so.1",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmng.so.1 loaded.
>=library-loaded,id="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so.8",target-name="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so.8",host-name="/home/so/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so.8",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so.8 loaded.
>=library-loaded,id="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblcms2.so.2",target-name="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblcms2.so.2",host-name="/home/so/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblcms2.so.2",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblcms2.so.2 loaded.
>&"warning: Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqmng.so.\nDo you need \"set solib-search-path\" or \"set sysroot\"?"
 Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqmng.so.
 Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
>&"\n"

>=library-loaded,id="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so",target-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so",host-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so loaded.
>=library-loaded,id="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/../../lib/libQt5Svg.so.5",target-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/../../lib/libQt5Svg.so.5",host-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/../../lib/libQt5Svg.so.5",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/../../lib/libQt5Svg.so.5 loaded.
>&"warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 2 libraries, e.g. /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so.\nUse the \"info sharedlibrary\" command to see the complete listing.\nDo you need \"set solib-search-path\" or \"set sysroot\"?"
 Could not load shared library symbols for 2 libraries, e.g. /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so.
 Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
 Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
>&"\n"

>=library-loaded,id="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.so",target-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.so",host-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.so",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.so loaded.
>&"warning: Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.so.\nDo you need \"set solib-search-path\" or \"set sysroot\"?"
 Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.so.
 Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
>&"\n"

>=library-loaded,id="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.so",target-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.so",host-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.so",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.so loaded.
>=library-loaded,id="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtiff.so.5",target-name="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtiff.so.5",host-name="/home/so/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtiff.so.5",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtiff.so.5 loaded.
>=library-loaded,id="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjbig.so.0",target-name="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjbig.so.0",host-name="/home/so/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjbig.so.0",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjbig.so.0 loaded.
>&"warning: Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.so.\nDo you need \"set solib-search-path\" or \"set sysroot\"?"
 Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.so.
 Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
>&"\n"

>=library-loaded,id="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.so",target-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.so",host-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.so",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.so loaded.
>&"warning: Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.so.\nDo you need \"set solib-search-path\" or \"set sysroot\"?"
 Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.so.
 Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
>&"\n"

>=library-loaded,id="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.so",target-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.so",host-name="/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.so",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
 Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.so loaded.
>&"warning: Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.so.\nDo you need \"set solib-search-path\" or \"set sysroot\"?"
 Could not load shared library symbols for /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.so.
 Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
>&"\n"
```

And left part of Debuger log window i have this:

```
68show version
69show debug-file-directory
70set print object on
71set breakpoint pending on
72set print elements 10000
73set unwindonsignal on
74set width 0
75set height 0
Setting up inferior...
76set sysroot /home/so/raspi/sysroot
77set substitute-path /usr/src /home/so/raspi/sysroot/usr/src
78python sys.path.insert(1, '/home/so/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/share/qtcreator/debugger/')
79python sys.path.append('/home/so/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/data-directory/python')
80python from gdbbridge import *
81python theDumper.loadDumpers({"token":81})
82-interpreter-exec console "set target-async off"
83set solib-search-path  /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats
Setting breakpoints...
84unset environment CINNAMON_VERSION
85unset environment DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
86unset environment DESKTOP_SESSION
87unset environment DISPLAY
88unset environment GDMSESSION
89unset environment GDM_LANG
90unset environment GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE
91unset environment GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID
92unset environment GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT
93unset environment GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS
94unset environment GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
95unset environment GPG_AGENT_INFO
96unset environment GTK_MODULES
97unset environment GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING
98unset environment HOME
99unset environment LANG
100unset environment LANGUAGE
101unset environment LOGNAME
102unset environment PATH
103unset environment PWD
104unset environment QT_ACCESSIBILITY
105unset environment QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON
106unset environment QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME
107unset environment SESSION_MANAGER
108unset environment SHELL
109unset environment SSH_AGENT_PID
110unset environment SSH_AUTH_SOCK
111unset environment USER
112unset environment XAUTHORITY
113unset environment XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
114unset environment XDG_DATA_DIRS
115unset environment XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR
116unset environment XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
117unset environment XDG_SEAT
118unset environment XDG_SEAT_PATH
119unset environment XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
120unset environment XDG_SESSION_ID
121unset environment XDG_SESSION_PATH
122unset environment XDG_SESSION_TYPE
123unset environment XDG_VTNR
124-file-exec-and-symbols "/home/so/Qt_Test_Projects/build-new_sd-Raspberry_Pi-Debug/new_sd"
125target extended-remote tcp:192.168.7.2:10001
Attached to stopped application.
126-gdb-set remote exec-file /home/pi/Desktop/new_sd/bin/new_sd
127-exec-run
Thread group i1 created.
Thread 1 created.
Library /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 loaded.
Running.
Application started.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so loaded.
Library /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 loaded.
Library /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 loaded.
Library /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so.2 loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpng16.so.16 loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdouble-conversion.so.1 loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgthread-2.0.so.0 loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.so.0 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdrm.so.2 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglapi.so.0 loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpcre.so.3 loaded.
Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so loaded.
Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5EglFSDeviceIntegration.so.5 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfontconfig.so.1 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfreetype.so.6 loaded.
Library /opt/vc/lib/libbrcmEGL.so loaded.
Library /opt/vc/lib/libbrcmGLESv2.so loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmtdev.so.1 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libinput.so.10 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libxkbcommon.so.0 loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libudev.so.1 loaded.
Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libts-0.0.so.0 loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libexpat.so.1 loaded.
Library /opt/vc/lib/libbcm_host.so loaded.
Library /opt/vc/lib/libvchiq_arm.so loaded.
Library /opt/vc/lib/libvcos.so loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libevdev.so.2 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libwacom.so.2 loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdbus-1.so.3 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgudev-1.0.so.0 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgobject-2.0.so.0 loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsystemd.so.0 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libffi.so.6 loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libselinux.so.1 loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblzma.so.5 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblz4.so.1 loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcrypt.so.20 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libresolv.so.2 loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmount.so.1 loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgpg-error.so.0 loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libblkid.so.1 loaded.
Library /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libuuid.so.1 loaded.
Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-brcm-integration.so loaded.
Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so loaded.
Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.so loaded.
Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so loaded.
Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so.62 loaded.
Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqmng.so loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmng.so.1 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so.8 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblcms2.so.2 loaded.
Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so loaded.
Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/../../lib/libQt5Svg.so.5 loaded.
Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.so loaded.
Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.so loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtiff.so.5 loaded.
Library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjbig.so.0 loaded.
Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.so loaded.
Library /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.so loaded.
```

What can i do to solve this problem? 
if i don't get the answer i prefer to install qt in pi zero and do my work vi ssh.

My this question link at Qt community:
[Qt cross compilation *QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program* error](https://forum.qt.io/topic/103716/qt-cross-compilation-qopenglshaderprogram-could-not-create-shader-program-error)
Thanks.

Comment: This seems related to a recent RPI update. I have been using Qt with RPI for 2 years now. Today I ran "rpi-update" and I get the same errors as you.